# React bug; setState() function calling other setstate function and preventing re-render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate

I'm working on a productivity tool site where users can add a task and edit or delete it, but I've got a bug going on with the button for saving a task once you're done editing. After some debugging, I realized that for some reason the "Save" button `onCLick` is calling the `handleSaveTask` function and then for some reason the `handleEditTask` function is also getting called, which sets the state of `isEditing` back to true, so that it stays in the edit mode.

Anyone got any idea what's going on here and how I can fix it? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './TaskList.css'

interface taskList {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    start: number;
    end: number;
}

interface TaskListProps {
    tasks: taskList[];
    onChangeTask: Function;
    onDeleteTask: Function;
}

interface TaskProps {
    task: taskList;
    onChange: Function;
    onDelete: Function;
}

export const TaskList: React.FC <TaskListProps> = ({tasks, onChangeTask, onDeleteTask}) => {
    return (
        <div className='center'>
            <h2 className='tasksTitle'>Tasks</h2>
            <div className='taskTitle'>
                <p className='taskTitle1'>Task Name</p>
                <p className='taskTitle2'>Range</p>
            </div>
                {tasks.map((task) => (
                    <Task key={task.id} task={task} onChange={onChangeTask} onDelete={onDeleteTask} />
                ))}
        </div>
    );
}

const Task: React.FC <TaskProps> = ({task, onChange, onDelete}) => {
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    let taskContent;

    const handleEditTask = () => {
        console.log("in Handle Edit Task");
        setIsEditing(true);
    }

    const handleSaveTask = () => {
        console.log("in Handle Save");
        setIsEditing(false);
    }

    if (isEditing) {
        taskContent = (
        <div id='editTask'>
            <input
            value={task.name}
            className="input inputName"
            onChange={(e) => {
                onChange({
                ...task,
                name: e.target.value,
                });
            }}
            />
            <input
            value={task.start}
            className="input inputNumber"
            onChange={(e) => {
                onChange({
                ...task,
                start: e.target.value,
                });
            }}
            />
            <input
            value={task.end}
            className="input inputNumber"
            onChange={(e) => {
                onChange({
                ...task,
                end: e.target.value,
                });
            }}
            />
            <button className="button buttonPrimary addButton" onClick={() => handleSaveTask()}>Save</button>
        </div>
        );
    } else {
        taskContent = (
        <>
            <div className='taskContent'>
                <p className='taskContentItem1'>{task.name}</p>
                <p className='taskContentItem2'>{task.start}-{task.end}</p>
                <div className='taskContentItem3'>
                    <button className='button buttonPrimary' onClick={() => handleEditTask()}>Edit</button>
                    <button className="button buttonSecondary" onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}>X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
        );
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className='center' >
            <label className='taskList'>
            <div className='taskListItem1'>
                {taskContent}
            </div>
            </label>
            </div>
        </>
    );
    }
```

[Console output when pressing "Save" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgZ4s.png)

You can also view a live demo here: [Demo](https://diceroll.lili4x4.com)

I tried adding a useEffect hook with `isEditing` in the dependency array, but it caused an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example or sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, in the `return` statement of `Task`, remove the `<label>` that is wrapping the `taskListItem1` div

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why that's the solution?

Comment: I haven't explored it enough to give a concrete explanation, but i believe it may related to event propagation - the click event may have been bubbling up to the label by the time react had re-rendered the content within the label